# Redis memory problems. Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, redis

I use redis for caching 2 entities (phones, authorities). Suddenly ran into memory problems. I do believe its because of caching, but can't figure out the cause. Can Hibernate enable 2nd level cache without `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true` in a way when my app would somehow have 2 caches for same entities? If it's not the case maybe the *TTL=6h* causing this leak?

**Update**

[image: Grafana Monitoring]
Added a link to cluster metrics where you can see the 4x cpu utilization

Comment: Could you please elaborate those memory problems?

Comment: @usuario updated with metrics monitoring image